# Infinite loop in NSFetchedResultsControllers controllerDidChangeContent method

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, infinite-loop

I have `UITableViewController` table and fetched rows from Core Data using `NSFetchedResultsController`. My `tableView` is responsible for layering data. Eatch row position represents layer (at zero row highest layer, n - row lowest). Lets say we have object with name `Layers *layers`. When I create new layer, it needs to go to 1st row (`indexPath.row == 0`) in the table and needs to get `layers.layer.position = 0`. When I create new layer or some other changes are made (move, delete) I need to refresh Core data object `layers` (each layer needs to get new position value). But if I refresh layers position by calling `[self updateLayersPosition]` method iside of `controllerDidChangeContent` method it goes to infinite loop because everytime on every old layer value change it returns to the same `controllerDidChangeContent` method again and again. So the question is how to "bind" table row or fetched controllers `indexPath.row` with `layers.layer.position`? Maybe I can some how stop `fetchedresultscontroller` from fetching, do updates and then start fetching again? Or maybe there is some other way to do it?

Here is the code:

```
-(void)updateLayers{
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]; i++) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i 
                                                    inSection:0];
            ((Layer *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]).layer.position = i;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self updateLayers];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: You cannot perform any changes to your context in `controllerDidChangeContent:`, that'd obviously cause an infinite loop.

Comment: So where it would be safe to put call to that method?

Comment: Depends on how you've programmed your app. Not here, though.

Comment: But if I want to make UITableViewController responsible for 'layering' then there is no need of mine code in other classes. It would be nice if I add new layer to layers object, this UITableViewController class do layering for me. So what method of NSFetchedResultsController or UITableViewController I need to use to change layers.layer.position value with dependency of indexPath.row value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the `willChange` / `didChange` methods in `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` are called after you modify Core Data objects. So if you modify any `NSManagedObject` inside `controllerDidChangeContent:`, it will trigger `controllerDidChangeContent:` again, leading to the infinite loop.

You can think about these delegate callbacks as a controller saying "You have changed something in your Core Data model, now let's update the UI (the `UITableView`). The general pattern you should follow is:

- make one or more changes (additions, modifications, deletions) in `NSManagedObjects`
- save `NSManagedObjectContext`
- in the methods of `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`: update the `UITableView` to reflect the changes (add, reload, delete table view rows)

So you probably want to do something like that:

```
//in the method in which you add a new Layer object
- (void)addLayer {
  Layer *layer = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Layer" inManagedObjectContext:context];
  //recalculate the position of all the other layers
  //save NSManagedObjectContext
}
```

The key is to update the `position` of each layer immediately after adding new layer, and then save the context. Then `NSFetchedResultsController` will take care of "binding" the layer's position to the row in the table, as you wanted (I assume that you use the `position` property in a sort descriptor used in a fetch request). If you implement these `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods as proposed in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate/controllerDidChangeContent:), it should do the job:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
    atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
    newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                  atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: I did what you said I implemented all my code in addLayer method and now layering works! Thanks.